# PowerShell variable interpolation in command line arguments

Tags: json, string, powershell, escaping, interpolation

**Description**

I'm having some trouble with passing a JSON string correctly into a command. I believe that I have recreated the problem that I'm experiencing in the test believe. The JSON string uses double quoted strings that also contain double quotes in the string body.

**The Problem:**

When I invoke the Powershell script directly with the arguments, the script echos the JSON string correctly. When I invoke the PowerShell script using `powershell.exe`, the JSON string appears to be evaled or parsed in such as way that the double quotes are removed (thus making the JSON string invalid).

**Examples:**

```
# Contents test.ps1 file
echo $args[0]
echo $args[1]

# Back to PowerShell
> $a='bar'
> $b="{`"foo`": `"$a`"}"
> $b
{"foo": "bar"} # <-- Looks correct
```

When I invoke the test.ps1 file directly, the output looks as I would expect:

```
> .\test.ps1 foo $b
foo
{"foo": "bar"} # <-- Looks correct
```

However, if I go one level of indirection further and use the `powershell.exe` to invoke the command, I do not get the desired result:

```
> powershell.exe ".\test.ps1 foo $b"
foo
foo: bar # <-- Wrong... The curly brackets have been removed, as if it's been evaled.

> powershell.exe -command ".\test.ps1 foo $b"
foo
foo: bar # <-- Wrong... For the same reasons as the last example
```

I'm trying to determine how I can get the powershell.exe command to output the full JSON string with quotes.

Answer (score 4):

When you pass powershell.exe a string, it invokes it as an expression.

```
powershell.exe "Get-Date"
```

This is why PowerShell invokes your string.

You can fix your issue like so:

```
$a='bar'
$b="{`"foo`": `"$a`"}"
powershell.exe -command {.\test.ps1 'foo' $args[0]} -args $b
```